# CoffeeScript - Issue with space

Tags: javascript, compilation, coffeescript

Following CoffeeScript

```
if eachController.indexOf("Controller.js") isnt -1
  controller = require(controllersFolderPath + eachControllerName)
  controller.register server
```

Gets complied to this JavaScript code

```
if (eachController.indexOf("Controller.js") !== -1) {
  controller = require(controllersFolderPath + eachControllerName);
  controller.register(server);
}
```

But when a extra space added after indexOf, the !== -1 becomes part of indexOf.

```
if eachController.indexOf ("Controller.js") isnt -1
    controller = require(controllersFolderPath + eachControllerName)
    controller.register server
```

Into

```
if (eachController.indexOf("Controller.js" !== -1)) {
    controller = require(controllersFolderPath + eachControllerName);
    controller.register(server);
}
```

Just wanted to know if its a bug or standard syntax which I should always care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes if you do the second form coffee will guess that you mean

```
if eachController.indexOf (("Controller.js") isnt -1)
    controller = require(controllersFolderPath + eachControllerName)
    controller.register server
```

than

```
if eachController.indexOf ("Controller.js") isnt -1
    controller = require(controllersFolderPath + eachControllerName)
    controller.register server
```

so you should be careful with smartness of coffee that is not so hard to do.(-:

Answer (score 0):

I would completely do away with the brackets '()' altogether and do this:

```
if -1 isnt eachController.indexOf "Controller.js"
  controller = require "#{controllersFolderPath}#{eachControllerName}"
  controller.register server
```

I also try to make use of the String interpolation, 
i.e. "#{controllersFolderPath}#{eachControllerName}"

Get's easier to read once you get used to it.

You can also try adding extra spaces after the 'indexOf' part, you will see that the coffee compiler ignores it and it doesn't break the function call.

Comment: Complete do away with brackets is not helping and resulting into same code as space with brackets, have u tried with compiler?

Comment: Updated to reverse the expression, essentially the same thing, but does away with the brackets.